# Wordpress PHP query is pulling the wrong database entry

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

first question here!

I have a custom wordpress site in which I have a check out function that includes a discount/coupon code.

I have done the following to test the code:
- I have set-up three coupon codes in my database
- All three coupon codes are in the database with the correct information

When I try to input a coupon, the code is only applying the coupon rules of the last coupon entered.  It should instead by pulling the coupon code that matches the user input of `$couponcode`

I know there is something wrong with the way I'm assigning the `$couponID` but I can't figure out how to do it correctly.

Note: I am aware of the mis-spelling of: `cooupon_title`. however it's set-up this way in the database, so that's not the error.

```
<?php       
$couponCode = '';
$couponMessage = '';
$discountAmount = 0;
$couponId = 0;
if(isset($_POST['couponCode']) && !empty($_POST['couponCode'])) {  
    $couponCode = $_POST['couponCode']; }       
if(!empty($couponCode)) {
    $args = array('posts_per_page' => 1,'offset' => 0,'category' => '', 'category_name' => '', 'orderby' => 'date','order' => 'DESC','include' => '', 'exclude' => '','meta_key' => '','meta_value' => '','post_type' => 'coupons','post_mime_type' => '','title' => $couponCode,'post_status' => 'publish','suppress_filters' => 'true');  
    $couponDbData = get_posts($args);
    $couponResultData = '';
      if(isset($couponDbData[0]) && !empty($couponDbData[0])) {
        $couponResultData = $couponDbData[0];
      } else {
        $couponMessage = 'Invalid coupon code';
      }

    if(isset($couponResultData->ID) && !empty($couponResultData->ID))
        $couponId = $couponResultData->ID;

    if(!empty($couponId)) { 
       $expiry_condition = get_post_meta($couponId,'expiry_condition',true);
       $expiry_value = get_post_meta($couponId,'expiry_value',true);
       $no_of_use = get_post_meta($couponId,'no_of_use',true);

       $appyCoupon = false;
          if($expiry_condition=='use') {
            if($expiry_value > $no_of_use) {
               $appyCoupon = true;
            } else {
               $couponMessage = 'Coupon has expired.';
            }
            } else {
               $couponExpireTime = strtotime($expiry_value);
               $currentTime = time();

               if($couponExpireTime > $currentTime) {
                 $appyCoupon = true;
               } else {
                 $couponMessage = 'Coupon has expired.';
               }
               }

if($appyCoupon) {
  $cooupon_title = get_post_meta($couponId,'cooupon_title',true);
  $coupon_type = get_post_meta($couponId,'coupon_type',true);
  $coupon_value = get_post_meta($couponId,'coupon_value',true);

if($coupon_type=='$') {
  $discountAmount = $coupon_value;
 } else {
  $discountAmount = ($orderAmount*$coupon_value)/100;
 }

 $grandTotal -= $discountAmount;
  }                 
  } 
 }
```

this is my test output:

```
if($appyCoupon) { ?>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 makeOrderDetailsrow">
   <label class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">Discount <?php echo '( Apply coupon '.$couponCode.' from the following sources '.$couponId.' '.$cooupon_title.' '.$coupon_value.' '.$coupon_type.')'; ?></label>
    <span class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">- $<?php echo (number_format($discountAmount,2)); ?></span>
    </div>
```

The output after "from the following sources" shows the code is pulling the last entry in the DB rather than the one that matches the `$couponCode`.   Any advice or suggestions?  thank you

Answer (score 1):

According to the codex, the args for get_posts does not include 'title', https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts.

Wordpress has a function to query the post by the title,  `get_page_by_title( $page_title, $output, $post_type );`http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title

By the way, you don't have to include the whole list of $args in the get_posts query, just those you want to change from the default. For example,

```
$args = array(
'post_type'        => 'coupon',
);
```

Will override the default of `'post_type'        => 'post'`, without changing `'posts_per_page'   => 5`.